# Get child element of parent with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a page with automatically generated HTML code as follows:

```
<span>
<img class="myimage" src="example.jpg"/>
<button onclick="do()">Do something</button>
</span>

<span>
<img class="myimage" src="example2.jpg"/>
<button onclick="do()">Do something</button>
</span>
```

I tried the following jquery code to retrieve the image element and store in variable, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
function do() {
    var pic = $(this).parent().find(".myimage");
    //do something                      
}
```

Comment: One of the problems is this: If you open your web console, you'll find an error there: `do` is not a valid function name, as it's a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You can't have a function called `do`; `do` is a keyword.
2. `this` within your function will be a reference to the global object, not the button that was clicked.

To fix it:

1. Change the name of the function.
2. Either hook it up with modern techniques like [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) (then `this` will refer to the button), or change your `onclick` attribute to pass `this` into it and use the first argument.

Here's an example with `on`:

```js
$(".do-something-btn").on("click", function() {
    var pic = $(this).parent().find(".myimage");
    alert(pic.attr("src"));
});
```

```html
<span>
<img class="myimage" src="example.jpg"/>
<button class="do-something-btn">Do something</button>
</span>

<span>
<img class="myimage" src="example2.jpg"/>
<button class="do-something-btn">Do something</button>
</span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's an example passing `this` into the function:

```js
function doSomething(element) {
    var pic = $(element).parent().find(".myimage");
    alert(pic.attr("src"));
};
```

```html
<span>
<img class="myimage" src="example.jpg"/>
<button onclick="doSomething(this)">Do something</button>
</span>

<span>
<img class="myimage" src="example2.jpg"/>
<button onclick="doSomething(this)">Do something</button>
</span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function `this` refers to window object.

To make the function work, each button should pass `this`, i.e. itself, to the function. Also, as ***@T.J.Crowder*** mentioned in comments, you can't use `do` as a function name - it's [reserved keyword](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm).

```
<span>
<img class="myimage" src="example.jpg"/>
<button onclick="func(this)">Do something</button>
</span>

<span>
<img class="myimage" src="example2.jpg"/>
<button onclick="func(this)">Do something</button>
</span>

function func(ele) {
  var pic = $(ele).parent().find(".myimage");
  //do something
}
```

---

Or you can use [jQuery click event](https://api.jquery.com/click/) handler inside handler you can use `this` to refer the clicked dom element.

```js
$('.myimage + button').click(function() {
  var pic = $(this).parent().find(".myimage");
  //do something
})
```